# Call a function in the format var.function()

Tags: javascript, function, syntax, parameters, call

I was interested in ways you could call a function.

For example, the native function `scrollIntoView()` can be called like `el.scrollIntoView()` with `el` being a parameter in the function.

I want to know if I could create something similar.
Is this behavior reserved for native functions, or could you code it yourself?

Thank you!

Comment: `scrollIntoView` is a method of the `Element` class. It has no parameters in your example. In other words, `el` has to be an instance of that class, or there's no `scrollIntoView()` method you can call. You can absolutely create your own [classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) though. This is a basic feature of object oriented programming, which is fully supported by JS since ECMA2015.

Comment: You can call `scrollIntoView` with `el` *not* being an instance of that class, like so: `document.querySelector(div).scrollIntoView()`. `querySelector` is not an instance of that class, is it not?

Comment: It's not, but the value it returns is.

Comment: `document.querySelector(div)` returns an element or `null`, so unless the selector doesn't match any element, it's absolutely an instance of that class, and therefore you can call the available methods on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simply an object you access property of, it's the most basic syntax

```js
const el = {
  param: "My function trigger",
  myFunction() {
    console.log(this.param);
  }
}

el.myFunction();
```

The created elements you talk about are all instances of classes that inherit the base class [Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element). As such they share same parts of the interfaces and they have similar callable methods, ex:

```js
class el {
  constructor(param){
    this.param=param;
  }
  myFunction() {
    console.log(this.param);
  }
}

const el1 = new el("My function param 1");
const el2 = new el("My function param 2");
el1.myFunction();
el2.myFunction();
```

Comment: What if is put dynamically, for example `el` is `document.querySelector(...)`?  eg. `document.querySelector('div').myFunction()`

Comment: @barhatsor No, don't store your logic or data in elements, use your own objects.

Comment: It is usually ill advised to modify the existing prototypes as different pieces of code can interfere with each other

Comment: I'm pretty sure OP is new to oo concepts in general (and return values, apparently); I don't think this question is about extending prototypes at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can extend the Element prototype although it is generally not a good practice extending native objects due to potential collisions

```js
Element.prototype.foo = function() {
  // do something the the element which is `this`
  console.log('id:', this.id)
}

document.querySelector('div').foo()
```

```html
<div id="1">Some content</div>
```